# Generating Mongo Query

Tags: mongodb

I am a new Mongo DB user, so please bear with me.

I have a Mongo database that stores usage logs, and for each `jobID`, there is a list of executables stored in a field called `"exec"`, which constitute a workflow.

I want to query the database to generate the number of times pairs of software are used as part of a job.

Ex.

> If `softwareA` and `softwareB` where used in the same `jobID` 20
>   times the query would return 20 for this pair, and I would like this
>   to recursively check all pairs of software.

Can someone make a recommendation as to how to construct a query?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the aggregation framework? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-examples/ What were your results when you tied that? I don't understand what you mean by recursively check all pairs.

Comment: yes, you will need to use the aggregation framework. For more detailed help, please, post some specifics about your data (a findOne() would help) and what you expect your result to look like